# SQL Contains: Escapar operadores de consulta

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

Tenía una query funcionando desde hace tiempo (montada por JPA) cuando de repente me ha dado una excepción:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [99999]; error code [29902]; could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)

En resumen, me da **SQL state [99999]; error code [29902];** que es un problema en los parámetros.

La query que se monta (a grandes rasgos) y que da problemas es esta:

```
select * from mytabla where CONTAINS(campo1, 'BT');
```

Después de un poco de *google-fu* he descubierto que [BT es un **operador de consulta** del contains](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqoper.htm) y, como en ese caso va sin los parámetros que debería, pues da el pete.

Este error se puede reproducir buscando `NOT`, `DIFMERGE`, `ABOUT`, `AND`.. y muchos otros que vienen en ese link.

**Pregunta**:

¿Hay alguna forma de "*escapar*" la palabra **`BT`** (o cualquier función de esas), para que oracle se piense que es una palabra y no una función?

El contains lo monto así:

```
return builder.greaterThan(
        builder.function("CONTAINS", Integer.class, exp, builder.literal(((String) param.getValue()).toUpperCase())),
        0);
```

EDIT: Por probar algo he probado a codificar en unicode la palabra BT, pero tampoco funciona, da el mismo error.

> select * from myTabla WHERE CONTAINS(campo1, UNISTR('\0042\0054')) > 0

Comment: la query las has realizado con Criteria o con HQL?

Comment: Pues con Spring JPA, implementando yo el toPredicate del Specification.

Answer (score 1):

Porque no pruebas

```
> select * from myTabla WHERE campo1 like '%bt%'
```

Esto buscara todo lo que sea similar a "bt"

Answer (score 1):

### `{texto}`

Las llaves escapan a un string completo, tomándolo como literal.

<sup>* [*Special Characters in Oracle Text Queries*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqspcl.htm#i1006222).</sup>

```sql
select * from mytabla where CONTAINS(campo1, '{BT}');
```

Consideraciones:

- Se debe incluir al string completo dentro de las llaves. Consultas con textos como `{BT}%fin` son tomadas como 2 tokens diferentes.
- Para escapar una `}` dentro de las llaves se usa `}}`.
- Si tan solo se desea escapar un único caracter, se puede usar la `\`. Ejemplo: `hola\!` (sino el `!` se interpretaría como soundex).